# Creating a formal system which corresponds to multiplication (of natural numbers)

Tags: logic, foundations, formal-systems

I've begun studying mathematical logic with Hodel's '[An Introduction to Mathematical Logic](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486497852.html)', and have just learnt about formal systems and their components. In the textbook, Hodel gives as an example of a formal system the system 'ADD', whose theorems correspond to true statements about addition; it is defined as follows:

- Symbols: $| \,,+,=$
- Formulae: statements of the form $x+y=z$ where $x,y$, and $z$ are expressions in $|$
- Axiom: $|+|=||$
- Rules of Inference: $\frac{x+y=z}{x|+y=z|}$ (R1) and $\frac{x+y=z}{y+x=z}$ (R2)

As an exercise (exercise 3 of section 1.3 for those with the book), Hodel then asks the reader to create a formal system 'MULT', which has theorems corresponding to our standard notions of multiplication; he also asks the reader to prove within this system that $|| \times ||| = ||||||$.

I believe I have a solution to this, but I would be grateful if someone wouldn't mind checking it for me - I'm new to this area of maths so want to make sure my fundamentals are strong. My system is defined as follows:

- Symbols: $|\, , \times, + , =$
- Formulae: statements of the form $x\times y = z$ or $x+y=z$ where $x, y,$ and $z$ are expressions in $|$
- Axioms: $|+|=||$ (A1) and $| \times x = x$ (A2)
- Rules of inference: $\frac{x+y=z}{x|+y=z|}$ (R1), $\frac{x+y=z}{y+x=z}$ (R2), $\frac{x\times y=z}{x|\times y=z+y}$ (R3), and $\frac{x\times y=z}{y\times x=z}$ (R4)

and my proof that $\vdash_{\text{MULT}}|| \times ||| = ||||||$:

1. $|\times||=||$ (A2)
2. $||\times || = ||+||$ (R3)
3. $|+|=||$ (A1)
4. $||+| = |||$ (R1)
5. $|+|| = |||$ (R2)
6. $||+|| = |||| = || \times || $(R1 and step 2)
7. $||| \times || = ||||+||$ (R3)
8. $|| + || = ||||$ (step 6 and previous)
9. $||||+|| = |||||| = ||| \times ||$ (R1 twice and step 7)
10. $ || \times ||| = ||||||$ (R4) $\square$

What makes me doubt whether this is the simplest solution is that I have included all of ADD within my new system, however I suppose this does reflect how multiplication is defined in terms of iterated addition.

Improvements, corrections, and other solutions welcomed and greatly appreciated :)

Comment: *Comment* : if the rule for formulas is : $x+y=z$  where $x,y$, and $z$ are expressions in |, then the conclusion of (R3) : $x| \times y= z+y$ is not well-formed, because $z+y$ is not "an expression in |".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks for that. I can’t see an obvious way to resolve this — is it reasonable just to adjust the definition of formulae in my system to include the form of R3?

Comment: There's no problem with the conclusion of R3, since x, z and z are symbols from the metalanguage, and not the language being define.

However, there's a problem with your axiom A2. You have to define it using only the symbols from the object language.

Here's a solution:
Reformulate A2 as: I x I = I. Then, the proof goes as follows:
1. I x I = I (A2)
2. II x I = II (R3)
3. III x I = III (R3)
4. I x III = III (R4)
5. II x III = IIIIII

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:
Reformulate A2 as: I x I = I. Then, the proof goes as follows:

1. I x I = I (A2)
2. II x I = II (R3)
3. III x I = III (R3)
4. I x III = III (R4)
5. II x III = IIIIII (R3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

- Symbols: $|, \cdot, =$
- Formulas of the form $a\cdot b = c$
- Axiom: $|\cdot|=|$
- Rules of inference: $\frac{a\cdot b = c}{a|\cdot b = b c} $ (R1) and $ \frac{a\cdot b = c}{a\cdot b| = ac}$ (R2)

Here is the proof:

1. $|\cdot|=|$ (Axiom)
2. $||\cdot|=||$ (R1)
3. $||\cdot||=||||$ (R2)
4. $||\cdot|||=||||||$ (R2)

Q.E.D.